# AzureAD PowerShell New-AzureRmRoleAssignment keeps failing

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, service-principal

I'm working on a powershell script that will create a Resource Group, register the included application (in this example, a Web Api) to the associated AAD.
But, when calling trying to assign `Reader` rights, it keeps on failing.

I've started from the basic deploy*.ps1 file that comes with the AzureResourceGroup template in Visual Studio (2015).

I'm running the following code:

```
#Requires -Version 3.0
#Requires -Module AzureRM.Resources
#Requires -Module Azure.Storage
Import-Module Azure -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-StrictMode -Version 3

Login-AzureRmAccount

$tenantWebSite = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "TheSiteName" -HomePage "http://MySignOnUrl" -IdentifierUris "http://MyIdentifierUrl" -Password "MyClientSecret"

$tenantWebSiteServicePrincipal = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $tenantWebSite.ApplicationId

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $tenantWebSite.ApplicationId
```

That last command (`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment`) keeps on failing with the following error:

```
09:58:26 - [ERROR] New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : PrincipalNotFound: Principal 
09:58:26 - [ERROR] 50f3d430c68b485b8c11a63552171550 does not exist in the directory 
09:58:26 - [ERROR] <MyTenantId>.
09:58:26 - [ERROR] At D:\dev_new_2010\cto\src\dev\d.tom.0\deploy\calidos.maat.deploy.azureresource
09:58:26 - [ERROR] group\Scripts\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:115 char:1
09:58:26 - [ERROR] + New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipa ...
09:58:26 - [ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
09:58:26 - [ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmRoleAssignment], Clo 
09:58:26 - [ERROR]    udException
09:58:26 - [ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleA 
09:58:26 - [ERROR]    ssignmentCommand
```

Normally, I run this script by using the deploy option in visual studio. When I run this script from a `Microsoft Azure PowerShell` command window, I get the same error.

BUT, when I run the exact command in that same powershell window, it works!

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName <ApplicationId>
```

Does anybody have an idea on why this would fail from within the ps1-file? I've also tried to explicitly define the scope, but that didn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, the previous "solution" was pure luck... Apparently, the `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` is created asynchronously. That method does immediately return an object, but the actual principal isn't created immediately...

I worked around this by adding a `Start-Sleep -s 15` command.

If this isn't enough, either increase it, or catch the error and wait another few seconds before trying again.

Comment: I found that I needed to add retry logic. It was sometimes taking 30 seconds for the creation to complete, so that I could add a role

Comment: Is there any other way to check if principal is created instead of New-AzureRmRoleAssignment try-catch retry logic?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but the route cause and solution was different.
This was my code:

`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $ServicePrincipal.ApplicationId -RoleDefinitionName $Role -Scope "/subscriptions/$($Subscription.Context.Subscription.Id)"`

and it always failed with the same error:

> New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Principal 7dfxxxxxxxxxxxxx1b1 does not
>   exist in the directory 3141xxxxxxxxxxxxxx736.

Waiting did not help.

The issue was resolved by using `$ServicePrincipal.Id` instead of `$ServicePrincipal.ApplicationId` for the `-ObjectId` parameter

Using `$ServicePrincipal.ApplicationId` is suggested by Example 5 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroleassignment?view=azurermps-5.5.0 which is not correct..

Comment: I upvoted the second suggestion above, but after testing, it seems it doesn't work for me. Not able to remove my upvote. Waiting with a bit of retry logic did the trick for me.